# GET HTML From URL Android

Tags: android

In my app i want show html from url :https://translate.google.com/?hl=vi#en/vi/hello
I try it wiht code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView tv1, tv2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,3000); // 3s max for connection
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 4000); // 4s max to get data
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters); // Create HTTP Client
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://translate.google.com/?hl=vi#en/vi/hello"); // Set the action you want to do
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
         // Executeit
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
        InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream with the response
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read line by line
            sb.append(line + "\n");

        String resString = sb.toString(); // Result is here
        Log.d("VD",resString);
        is.close(); // Close the stream
        //You can also add some params to the HttpClient to manage timeout and other stuff like that. Ex :

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
```

I've added :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But it not working.
and if you can just get the value of the  value

Answer (score 0):

Check the Status Code from response...it should be 200

```
int status=response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if(status==200)
{
//Write your try catch code here
}
```

if its not 200 than the problem is from link response